# Unreal Engine 4 In-game Screenshot

Tags: screenshot, game-engine, unreal-engine4

Is there a way to take a screenshot in UE4 while in-game and save it somewhere so that I can use it again as an image or something?

There is a HighResShot solution, but that saves it somewhere outside the range of the editor (you cannot reach it programmatically), is there another way of doing it, that allows me to access it in-game?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using HighResShot for taking the screenshots. As you mention, it saves this outside the range of the engine, in the "saved" folder. (In packaged builds, the saved content is in the user's appdata.) You can actually get this with `ProjectSavedDir()`, which returns this saved directory. https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/API/Runtime/Core/Misc/FPaths/index.html

It's C++, but you can expose this to Blueprints fairly easily. You can get the `ProjectSavedDir()/Screenshots` directory and load the images in-game. For doing this, I recommend the Ramas plugin (https://forums.unrealengine.com/development-discussion/blueprint-visual-scripting/4014-39-rama-s-extra-blueprint-nodes-for-you-as-a-plugin-no-c-required?3851-(39)-Rama-s-Extra-Blueprint-Nodes-for-You-as-a-Plugin-No-C-Required=)

Comment: I can get the path for the folders that hold the screenshots now, but is there a way to get the last image token instead? And how can I get the screenshot from the container folder even if I don't know the name of the image?

Comment: You can get the list of files as an array. Check this out: https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/61858/using-ffilemanagergeneric-for-listing-files-in-dir.html

Doing a For Each Loop and getting the file name of the last index should do the trick!