# Is there a way to take an ingame high res screenshot in UE4?

Tags: screenshot, unreal-engine4

So I am developing a VR app in Unreal and I'd like to give the user the ability to take a screenshot in game through the click of a button.

I am currently taking a screenshot through a console command but, it doesn't allow me to change the file location of where it goes. I don't think it will be intuitive enough to users to look into the AppData folder.

Is there a way to change this file location?

Does anyone know of any other ways to take a screenshot in game in Unreal Engine and save it to a folder or something similar?

Is there a function library or anything I can utilize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a really easy way to change where the screenshot gets saved at. I was really surprised how easy it was actually. Essentially, all you have to do is add an argument to the console command.

```
HighResShot 1920x1080 filename="D:/Screenshots/screenshot.png"
```

However, you need to ensure that the file name is unique, otherwise it will just overwrite the screenshot every time.

I ended up just grabbing Time Now and appending the date inside of the screenshot name. So that it ended up looking something like this:

```
HighResShot 1920x1080 filename="D:/Screenshots/screenshot_2020-6-5-8-40-01.png"
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this thread out:
[Unreal Engine 4 In-game Screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61829746/unreal-engine-4-in-game-screenshot/61847591#61847591)

You should continue to use the console command; it's the easiest way to do this in my opinion. In C++, you can expose your screenshot default folder with `ProjectSavedDir()`. That being said, you can get references of your screenshots and move them to another `FPath` location. For a bit of a better translation, take a look at these macros: https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/API/Runtime/Core/Misc/FPaths/index.html